# Modified data in QuestionTemplate for ASP Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-membership

I would like to create forgot password page, which is supported by membership provider. I use PasswordRecovery control which has QuestionTemplate and later on I have there literal with ID='Question' and when I display a webpage, instead of this literal password question is displayed.

And that's the point. I would like to display a little bit modified Question in this place. Is it possible? May I change Question before I display it (but I don't want to changed it in database)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the literal to be the text rather than using the properties of the PasswordRecovery control?  I am thinking that you should probably have a look at the Password Recovery page on MSDN. There is quite a lot to that control and without using the templates that go with it, it's probably overwriting it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.aspx